# Can you say some Real-life examples of interface and abstract class?

Tags: c#

i am little confusing to understanding the real-life examples of interface and abstract class in c#

1. interface
2. abstract class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it may be confusing for some people :)

An abstract class with no implementation looks like an interface.
Hovewer there are some differences.

An abstract class cannot be instantiated. It is used to be a base class for any inherited classes. It's kind of contract for other classes that inherits from it which force all subclasses to carry on same standards.

An interface isn't a class at all. It has no implementation.
I think main difference is that class can implement more than one interface, but only one class.